# Jquery display on link click question?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to display the following code below only when a user clicks a specific link. Is it possible with JQuery? If so how would I be able to do this?

Here is my code.

```
    function signedIN(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://update.php",
            data: "do=getID",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#status").text(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: 1. Write it to a div. 2. hide it on document load. 3.)show it it onclick event of specific link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a link with an ID of `update`:

```
<a id="update" href="update.php">Update</a>
```

Bind your `signedIN()` function to the link's click event:

```
$('#update').click(signedIN);
```

You'll need to add a `return false;` at the end of your function so the link doesn't actually proceed to `update.php` (the link's `href` value).

**EDIT:** here's a more complete code example so you can see how this all comes together:

```
function signedIN(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://update.php",
        data: "do=getID",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#status").text(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("some error occured, please try again later");
        }
    });

    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // You probably have other jQuery code here, so just place this line somewhere
    $('#update').click(signedIN);

});
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to JQuery I cant seem to get this to work with my code :(

Comment: @jphp: I provided a more complete example, hope it helps.